# spark checkpoint : error java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-checkpoint

**I have a current pipeline, where I do several transformations to my dataframe.**

It is important to insert checkpoints to assure an accepted execution time.

However from time to time I get this error from any of the checkpoints:

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task creation failed: java.io.FileNotFoundException

No such file or directory: /checkpoints/...../rdd-1002/part-00003
```

Can you please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Is it similar to this issue?
A complex logic is overwriting the RDD while a failing process is trying to recover.

[Spark not able to find checkpointed data in HDFS after executor fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52059382/spark-not-able-to-find-checkpointed-data-in-hdfs-after-executor-fails)

Comment: yes, but solution given there is not working, also its not an accepted answer

Comment: You might have to check the data to see what is causing the error first.
One possible way to solve this is to have a good `try`, `catch` or `Try` so that the error is handled in the logic to prevent the code block from error since you are just using the checkpoint for time management.